# ASP.NET windows authentication should always ask for credentials

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication

Problem statement :
I have implemented windows authentication on my website.
I have used following code in my web.config for authentication

```
   <authentication mode="Windows">
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
```

Now, the problem is that when I access the website, it takes the default ( windows) credentials and tries to login.

But I need that it should prompt the user for credentials so that user can enter domain-name\id and password of separate domain for authenticate (User will have VPN access to this other domain)

Comment: Just curious - why not create the web application the VPN accessible domain (instead of dealing with cross-AD/domain)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using `Digest Authentication` mode in IIS. Once enabled it will prompt always for UserName/Password to the end user.

You can read more about this type authentication here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778868(v=ws.10).aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754104(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using Windows Authentication use Forms Auth and check entered login and password in Domain.

There is a nice article on MSDN: [How To: Use Forms Authentication with Active Directory in Multiple Domains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650307.aspx)