# ASP.NET Windows Authentication: Always prompt for credentials?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I've inherited an application that uses Windows authentication. The problem is that I need to have the application always prompt for credentials because different people need to login and use it. My web.config is simple:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
  <allow roles="application_whitelist" />
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

So we add/delete users from "application_whitelist" to control access to the application. The problem, of course, is that we're not being prompted for our credentials. Is there any way to force this to occur? (I checked [ASP.NET windows authentication should always ask for credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790747/asp-net-windows-authentication-should-always-ask-for-credentials) but it was no help.)

Comment: You know that there's a simple automatic NTLM/Kerberos handshake which, depending on the browser, does the login-thing for you. Are the users actually auhenticated, or do they have access as Anonymous to your web application?

Comment: I don't know anything about Kerberos, so no, I didn't know there's a simple automatic handshake which will do it for me. Can you provide (or point to) more details?

My users are authenticated; they don't have access as Anonymous.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc246219.aspx, and do some fiddling to get insight on the actual requests and responses...

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, @Andreas. I like learning new things, but are we sure this is the best way to go? Surely I'm not the only one who has come across this requirement? Would it (I'm just asking) perhaps be more straightforward to switch to Forms Authentication and use something like LDAP to access AD?

Comment: Btw, I'm not getting notified when someone adds a comment to this question. What have I done wrong? I have to keep checking to see if anything's been added.

Comment: It's not about the best way to go - some browser do the authentication stuff for you (and send your windows credentails along), others not ...

Answer (score 0):

What about clearing cache at the browser close event? Look at that [link](http://www.adopenstatic.com/cs/blogs/ken/archive/2005/04/12/14.aspx). I hope it will help you.

Comment: I haven't cleared the cache in code, but I have cleared it. I've even shut down the browser and opened a new one. It still remembers the previous user and logs them right in. And I would like this to work across multiple browsers -- not just IE.